# Grouping variables by their sequential occurence

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, sequence

Let's say I have a dataset:

```
RNGkind('Mersenne-Twister')
set.seed(24)
y = sample(c('a', 'b'),
           10, replace = T)
my.dataframe1 <- data.frame(y)
my.dataframe1
   y
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  b
5  b
6  b
7  a
8  b
9  b
10 a
```

I want to create another variable (`z`) that assigns a grouping value to the values in `y` based on the cluster they appear in. A 'cluster' in this case would have a single occurrence of several `a`s and `b`s, depending on whether `a` or `b` occurs first.

For example, a value of `1` would be assigned to the cluster of rows where `a` and `b` appear (rows `1:6`), a value of `2` would be assigned to the second cluster of rows (rows `7:9`).

The data frame would then look something like this:

```
   y z
1  a 1
2  a 1
3  b 1
4  b 1
5  b 1
6  b 1
7  a 2
8  b 2
9  b 2
10 a 1
```

It needs to work so that it will recognize the change whether `a` or `b` occur in the sequence first, e.g.:

```
set.seed(42)
y = sample(c('a', 'b'),
           10, replace = T)
my.dataframe2 <- data.frame(y)
my.dataframe2
   y
1  b
2  b
3  a
4  b
5  b
6  b
7  b
8  a
9  b
10 b
```

So that we'd still get the same result:

```
   y z
1  b 1
2  b 1
3  a 1
4  b 2
5  b 2
6  b 2
7  b 2
8  a 2
9  b 3
10 b 3
```

Other than doing it manually with `c()`, I can't figure out how to automate it, especially with a data set that's more than 1000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rle` comparing the first value in `y` column and then use `cumsum` and `rep` to generate the sequence.

```
my.dataframe1$z <- with(rle(my.dataframe1$y == my.dataframe1$y[1L]), 
                        rep(cumsum(values), lengths))
my.dataframe1

#   y z
#1  a 1
#2  a 1
#3  b 1
#4  b 1
#5  b 1
#6  b 1
#7  a 2
#8  b 2
#9  b 2
#10 a 3
```

**data**

```
my.dataframe1 <- structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `inverse.rle` with `rle`

```
my.dataframe1$z  <- with(my.dataframe1, inverse.rle(within.list(rle(!is.na(match(y, y[1]))),
                     values <- cumsum(values))))
my.dataframe1$z 
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

#### data

```
my.dataframe1 <- structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```